# How can i achieve this kind of view??(in List View)

Tags: android

[image]

Hi guys  i wan't to know that how can  i achieve this kind of view??what i can think is ListView inside  ScrollView but i don't think that will work the same way as  in the picture also i think listview inside a scroll view is not a very good practice.

also i  am thinking that can this be done via a parallax view??

Basically i am not asking for code(but if u can provide,i would be very grateful to you ;) )
but just the basic way explaining ,how i can achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

This is known as parallax scrolling.  Thankfully there are a variety of ways to do this, and even some really mature libraries to help you out.

The below article is a really great breakdown of someone trying to recreate the Profile screen in Google+:

http://antoine-merle.com/blog/2013/10/04/making-that-google-plus-profile-screen/

Here is a library that the article recommends, and one that I have used with great success in a few apps:

https://github.com/chrisjenx/Paralloid